# Configuring DNS for webs into Virtual machines (VM) on Azure

Tags: azure, iis-7, dns, virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I have a very simple scenario that I can´t make it work.

I created a virtual machine, installed iis, already can see landing page of IIS if I enter public IP on my browser, so it is well configured on firewalls and whatsoever...

Just for making this example more accurate, I changed port of that webpage to 8888, and also keeps working on my browser if I enter 1.1.1.1:8888... cool.

Now I want to associate my "contoso.com" address to this IP and specific port of my IIS.

Anybody knows how to do that??? Cause all I can find are lots of solutions talking about how to configure DNS to WEBPAGES.AZUREWEBSITES.NET, and I don´t have one of that... I have MYVM.CLOUDAPP.NET.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add a HOST (A) record in your public dns provider to point to your Azure VM Public IP Address. The port doesn't matter.